# How can I access enum atributes in HQL?

Tags: java, hibernate, enums, hql

I have an Enum like this:

```
TicketPriority {

LOW(4),
NORMAL(3),
HIGH(2),
IMMEDIATE(1);

private Integer index;

TicketPriority (Integer index){
    this.index = index;
}

public Integer getIndex(){
    return this.index;
}

public void setIndex(Integer index){
    this.index = index;
}
}
```

... and I have an Ticket entity that has a priority. The problem: I need to order my results by priority so I thought that this would work, but it didn't:

```
select t from Ticket t order by t.priority.index
```

I got an error from Hibernate. Any idea besides create Priority as an entity?

Thanks for any suggestion! :)

Comment: I'm confused... if your Ticket is an entity and it contains a Priority, wouldn't that make Priority an entity too for it to work in Hibernate in the first place?

Comment: Can't you post the error or stacktrace? It's just a shot in the dark without more details.

Comment: I will post the error later, but basically hibernate tells me that my index var doesn't exist. :(

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it this way.

HQL query is converted to SQL for execution, therefore all properties referenced in HQL query should be stored in the database. Since your `index` property is not stored in the database, HQL query with it can't be converted to SQL query.

You can use enums in `ORDER BY` clause of HQL query only to sort by the natural order of their database representation (i.e. names or ordinal numbers).

You have several options:

1. Organize your `enum`s so that order of their declarations matches the desired order of their `index`es and configure Hibernate to store them in the database as ordinal numbers. If it's already configured, in your case the desired query would be

   ```
   select t from Ticket t order by t.priority desc
   ```
2. Use `@Embeddable`/`<component>` class instead of `enum` to store `index` in the database.
3. Write a custom type to represent your enum as `index`.

Comment: Thanks buddy! I will try the first one. I didn't know that it was possible do this. It seems i have to use @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL) annotation. Thanks, one more time!